# How do I deserialize json to c# model if the json object has a name starting with an int

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, serialization

I'm trying to work on updating a JIRA API plugin because I need to do more with it than it's current limitations. The problem is Jira has a field of avatarUrls that have names like `48x48` `32x32` I am using `deserializer.Deserialize<CommentsContainer>(response)` in order to deserialize the json to an object. Any ideas how I might capture this information? I need these avatars displayed on my page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesn't the deserializer append an underscore to the name, so 48x48 becomes _48x48? You can try deserializing to a `dynamic` and looking at what the generated member names become. What deserializer are you using? json.net or the data contract serializer?

Comment: Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using? VS2015 has an option to paste JSON as classes, which will automatically generate member names.

Comment: I have vs2013 hopefully will upgrade soon. The underscores didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomender to use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) it is very useful librery for working with tricky Json like on Jira API. I have used this approach for your perpouse

**Entity:**

```
public class ProjectDescription : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Key { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avatarUrls")]
    public AvatarUrls AvatarUrls { get; set; } 
}  

public class AvatarUrls
{
  [JsonProperty("32x32")]
  public string Size32 { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("48x48")]
  public string Size48 { get; set; }
}
```

And just Deserialize your responce to Enity:

```
var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectDescription>>(response);
```

Comment: `JsonProperty` is not needed in `ProjectDescription`. Json.NET handles case.

Comment: I planned on using this if I couldn't find a better answer. I was trying to keep dependencies low.

Comment: If I don't hear anything using basic json deserialization I will accept this as the right answer. I will more than likely be using it.

Comment: You will needed many times aslo you can find JSON.NET in nuget :-) And don't forget about additional advantage like performance: 50% faster than DataContractJsonSerializer, and 250% faster than JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: I've used it a million times. Didn't know it was faster. Just dependency wise trying to avoid requiring too many. I'm just going to use it though. I think most applications we've used here use JSON.NET